# Davening Amidah quietly during Chazarat HaShatz

Tags: shemoneh-esrei

1. What is the custom when davening the amidah quietly. Assuming that someone is in the body of the amidah, I am aware that he has to stay quiet during kedusha, but if he is in Elokai netzor, he says “kodosh kodosh kodosh etc” and “Barooch kevod” - but does he stay quiet also for “yimloch”?
2. Whilst in Elokai netzor and beyond I assume he is ok to continue and say amen (but not “barooch overuch shemo”)
3. Can he say personal tefilot even though the tzibbur are in the main body of Chazarat HaShatz, and continue to just say amen to the brachot?

Comment: Thanks David for your question. You phrased it as if asking for a personal pesak which might have got it closed. So I edited it into the third person - if you don't like the edit, you can always turn the question back to the original form .

Answer (score 0):

There may be many views on this in Halacha so for a practical ruling one must consult your rav for what you should do since there are differences of shita between various nusach and minhag.

In my siddur on the back cover there is a chart for interruptions and responses. It says after saying the first yiyu l'ratzon then to respond only with the three main parts of kedusha which starts with the words "kadosh", "Baruch", and "yimloch".

Answer (score 0):

In regards to question 1, the MB in [122:4](https://www.sefaria.org/Mishnah_Berurah.122.4?lang=bi) says that the Halacha of answering kedusha in this instance, is similar to the Halacha of answering during Birchas Krias Shema which is discussed in [MB 66:17](https://www.sefaria.org/Mishnah_Berurah.66.17?lang=bi). Over there he says explicitly that it’s only Kadosh and Baruch not Yimloch;

> ולקדושה יאמר רק קדוש וברוך שזהו עיקר קדושה ולא ימלוך וכ"ש שלא יאמר נקדש ושאר דברים שמוסיפין בשבת

The [Shulchan Aruch Harav in 66:5](https://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=25072&st=&pgnum=258) says that there’s a machlokes if Yimloch is included or not.

In regards to question 2, the [MB 122:1](https://www.sefaria.org/Mishnah_Berurah.122.1?lang=bi) says that it’s permitted (not required) to answer amen on every bracha, however tachnunim that are said regularly are like Shemona Esrei and during saying that, one should only answer Amen for the main Brachos:

> א) שפיר דמי - היינו דמותר אפילו לענות סתם אמן וכ"ש אמן דהאל הקדוש וש"ת ואיש"ר וקדושה וברכו והא דמסיים בסוף הסעיף כדרך שמפסיק בברכת ק"ש ושם אינו מותר לסתם אמן וכנ"ל בסימן ס"ו שם הלא איירי ברגיל לומר תחנונים ע"כ עשאום עליו קבע ודמיין קצת לשמ"ע וברישא איירי במי שרגיל לומר לפרקים ע"כ אין להם דמיון לשמ"ע כלל ולפ"ז במדינותינו שאלהי נצור רגילין הכל לאומרו אין להפסיק בו לסתם אמן בין קודם שהתחילו בין באמצע

In regards to question 3, although the MB [124:17](https://www.sefaria.org/Mishnah_Berurah.124.17?lang=bi) says that one shouldn’t say additional prayers during chazaras hashatz, it is apparent from other places (R Chaim Kanievski in Ishei Yisroel 32:61 for example) that discuss how one can continue his private tefillas even after answering Kedusha etc., that the MB is referring to one who finished Shemona Esrei and now wishes to say tehillim or something, but davening before Yehi Ratzon is allowed.